Split into large dataset into equal buckets in pyspark
I have a super large dataframe 'df' with 20 Million members.
I want to be able to split this dataset into buckets of size 20K each. And I want the resultant buckets to be renamed as 'Group1', 'Group2' & so on. Instead of coding this manually I have looked into bucketizer but haven't had luck getting the code to run. How would I go about this?
The reason for splitting the dataset is the underlying Snowpark write function can handle only so much data at a time without timing out.

Are you using pandas on Snowflake? It may not have the limitation you are seeing with Snowpark dataframes. See https://docs.snowflake.com/developer-guide/snowpark/python/pandas-on-snowflake for more information.

I ended up using the ntile function to divide the large dataset into n equal parts

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
